# md-grid-list rowHeigh="fit" not working. Is there an alternative solution

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm creating an angular2 application with materialize design. I'm trying to create a layout where I want the layout to be divided into two parts. I used `md-grid-list` for that. Referred documentation https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview for that. `md-grid-list rowHeigh="fit"` not working. Is there an alternative solution to make the row height similar to height of the screen.

Here's the project.component.html file that I was working on.

```
<md-toolbar><h2>Projects</h2></md-toolbar>
<md-grid-list cols="50" rowHeight="fit" >
  <md-grid-tile [colspan]="15"> 1 </md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile [colspan]="35" >2</md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

When I provide `style="height:300px"` It looks like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz05n.png)

But I want to divide the whole screen into two.So that I used `cols="2"`.I can change the height to enable it to suit the whole screen. But I cannot give a fixed height to the content as it can be changed according to the data that'll be available inside the content.

Comment: please add your code where you are applying it

Comment: Hi I edited the question by addng the code. Great if you can save me today :)

Comment: i have answered your question make sure you have set some height to md-grid-list and aslo cols="2" because you have defined 2 columns

Comment: Hi,  I've edited the question. Great if you can help me..

Comment: well this is not a good approach you should accept the answer if its according to your question, and you should post a new question. any way let me update my answer

Comment: style="height: calc(100vh - 24px)"  you can do it with css

Comment: also vote it up :) thanks

Comment: Sorry about that I'm not much familiar with stuff here. I just wanted to attach the image. I could not attach it in a comment. That's why I edited the question. Thanks much for the help.(Y)

Comment: Its ok no problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can set any elements height to 100% with `style="height: calc(100vh - 24px)"` you have 2 columns but telling `cols=50` in `md-grid-list` also apply height to your `md-grid-list` for `rowHeight="fit"` to work

see documentation says

> Fit: Setting rowHeight to fit This mode automatically divides the
>   available height by the number of rows. Please note the **height of the
>   grid-list or its container must be set.**

```
<md-grid-list cols="2">
  <md-grid-tile style="height: calc(100vh - 24px)">1</md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile style="height: calc(100vh - 24px)">2</md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```